# neo4j example "myrestaurants-social" Errors

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I downloaded neo4j example "myrestaurants-social" from github, and then imported it to Eclipse 4.4.0.
But this project had 23 errors:

```
The method getPersistentState() is undefined for the type Recommendation<p>
The method getPersistentState() is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method getPersistentState() is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method getRelationshipId() is undefined for the type Recommendation<br>
The method getRelationshipId() is undefined for the type Recommendation<br>
The method getRelationshipId() is undefined for the type Recommendation<br>
The method getRelationshipId() is undefined for the type Recommendation<br>
The method getRelationshipId() is undefined for the type Recommendation<br>
The method getRelationshipId() is undefined for the type Recommendation<br>
The method hasPersistentState() is undefined for the type Recommendation<br>
The method persist() is undefined for the type Restaurant<br>
The method persist() is undefined for the type Restaurant<br>
The method persist() is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method persist() is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method persist() is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method persist() is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method persist() is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method persist() is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method persist() is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method persist() is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method persist() is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method relateTo(Restaurant, Class<Recommendation>, String) is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
The method relateTo(UserAccount, String) is undefined for the type UserAccount<br>
```

I think some classes don't have these methods that are in ERRORS description.

How can i solve these errors?

---

When building maven, i find a Error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException : Configuration problem:                                                              You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.1. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.1 schema.
```

It's my application-context-security.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
```

Comment: Does the build succeed when running via maven directly?

Comment: @Stefan Armbruster  i added maven errors. :)